# Google maps in Morocco

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to use Google maps in a Webapp that is targeted for Moroccans, the thing is the map works fine but the borders for Morocco is not complete. it's a political issue and I'm afraid that is going to cause problems for me. My question is: Is it possible to load in my App a different map that shows the Moroccan perspective of the borders knowing that I've seen it before in a GPS App that uses Google Maps. I tried using a different domain like maps.google.co.ma instead of maps.google.com but it didn't work.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you have a map (and map tiles) you can make a [custom map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#CustomMapTypes) using them.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `region:"MA"` in your API call options

if you're using a link

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&region=MA
```